# Search function not working

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, search

I am using SSHOP theme for my woocommerce store. when i search anything from home page search url works fine and following search permalink shows.

**https://techcart.pk/?s=abc**

but when i search when from product page or category page search result did not find anything and following permalink shows.

**https://techcart.pk/product/8mm-led-10pcs/?s=abc**

i want to rewrite the above permalink to be shown as **https://techcart.pk/?s=abc**

please help

Answer (score 0):

Header `<form>` don't have `action=""` attribute. So basically what form do, when you search, is append `s=keyWord` in current url, that is why you have url like this https://techcart.pk/product/8mm-led-10pcs/?s=abc.
What you need to to is to add `action=""` in `<form>`.
You can inspect element in sidebar search field and you can see this markup:

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="https://techcart.pk/">
```

So basically you need to do the same on header search. Just replace action URL to be dynamically, like this:

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">
```